# How to display array of arrays in JSP data retrieved from servlet . The record displays nothing while trying to access from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

Want to Display the below data pattern in JSP page. {record.id} displays nothing could anyone help to resolve this.The Data is fetched from the mysql database from servlet and passed to JSP .

JSP CODE

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="record" items="${STUDENT_LIST}">  
          <td>${record.id}</td>
          <td>${record.sfirstName}</td>
          <td>${record.sgender}</td>
       </c:forEach>
   </tr>
</table>
```

DATA FORMAT

```
[getStudentDetails[id=1, sfirstName=Tom,  sgender=M],
[getStudentDetails[id=2,sfirstName=jerry,  sgender=M],
[getStudentDetails[id=3, sfirstName=scooby, sgender=M]]
```

Servlet code

students = studentDetailsDB.getStudents();

```
     request.setAttribute("STUDENT_LIST", students);
         
    request.getRequestDispatcher("studentDetailsView.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Student Class
public class getStudentDetails {

```
private int    id;
private String sfirstName;
private String sgender;


public getStudentDetails(int id, String sfirstName, String sgender) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sfirstName = sfirstName;
    this.sgender = sgender;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSfirstName() {
    return sfirstName;
}

public void setSfirstName(String sfirstName) {
    this.sfirstName = sfirstName;
}


public String getSgender() {
    return sgender;
}

public void setSgender(String sgender) {
    this.sgender = sgender;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "getStudentDetails[" + "id=" + id + ", sfirstName=" + sfirstName + ", sgender=" + sgender + ']';
}
```

}

DBO
while (rs.next()) {

```
            // retrieve data from result set row
            
              
             int      id           =  rs.getInt("studentId");
             String   sfirstName   =  rs.getString("sFirstName");
             String   sgender      =  rs.getString("gender");
             
          
            getStudentDetails tstudent = new getStudentDetails(id ,sfirstName,sgender); 
        
            student.add(tstudent);       
            
            }
```

Comment: `record.slastName` vs `sfirstName=scooby` ?

Comment: In your servlet do you add this data into your request or session?

Comment: students = studentDetailsDB.getStudents();
    
         request.setAttribute("STUDENT_LIST", students);
             
        request.getRequestDispatcher("studentDetailsView.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: Are you sure that `students = studentDetailsDB.getStudents();` is not empty?

Comment: No it is not empty  ${STUDENT_LIST} has the details in the format mentioned in the question . when I do foreach loop and try to get the data using {record.id} as mentioned in the question I dont get any output

Comment: a) check you logs for any errors.  b) check for any typos. c) Can you post your `Student` class here

Comment: posted student class and database resultset processing

Comment: In its current state your code does not compile.  `private String sFirstName;` then `this.sfirstName = sfirstName;`

Comment: corrected . I am getting the data in JSP the main issue is with the display of data using the for loop . I need help in displaying the data using for loop in JSP . I tried as I have mentioned in the question but it does not work . Could you please help . Thanks soo much for replying .

Answer (score 1):

In the JSP you provided, you do not include the taglib directive

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

For the `c:forEach`.

Without this, you'll get nothing.

Comment: Getting the below error  after adding this ,

Comment: Inside Catchorg.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: I have jar files in maven repository I tried adding it in dependencies but still it did not work <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Added this in xml and it worked

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: @VRR If this answer solved your issue, then please upvote and accept.

Comment: *Without this, you'll get nothing.* - very surprised that you don't even get a jasper error.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You'd think that would be surprising, but it's not. You don't get a Jasper error because the compiler "doesn't know" the c:forEach is "interesting". JSP doesn't care about the source text, (i.e. HTML, CSS, plain text, raw XML with arbitrary namespaces), so it will only look at the XML "bits" that look like directives it should care about. Since the taglib directive never told it about the "c:" namespace, it ignores it. There's nothing special about "c:", it's just convention.

Comment: I am unable to upvote If I try to upvote it says require at least 15 reputation .

Comment: @WillHartung Thank you for your explanation.  It makes sense.